# Crashlytics : stuck on "Verifying Installation..." step

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I want to use Crashlytics on my application. I followed every step but I'm stuck on "Verifying Installation..." step.

[image]

What is the problem ?

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. Can you zip up the following folder and send it to support@fabric.io so I can dig into your logs? ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.crashlytics.mac/v3/active

Comment: There isn't "com.crashlytics.data" in "Caches".

Comment: @Alexizamerican Any progress on finding solution  ? I am also facing same issue with xcode 7 and latest fabric sdk

Comment: @MayurKothawade unfortunately, this error is tough to diagnose without seeing your log files. If you can zip the folder above and email me at support@fabric.io, I can take a look.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same issue. I also don't see `com.crashlytics.data` a folder in my Caches. Not sure how to resolve it? Does it related to company private network? Somewhere related to proxy settings?

Comment: I see `Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2096, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}` in XCode log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
I put my code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication)` instead of func `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)`

Comment: What code did you put in applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication)?

Comment: Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) I belive

Comment: Probably same as @lucianoenrico's solution

Comment: WTF! It worked! I've been using Crashlytics for ages and this is the first time I've find this problem. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too, weird.

Comment: `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` this throw compilation problem for me. I am using `Objective C`

Answer (score 18):

setDebugMode = YES

set below code before  [Fabric with:@[ TwitterKit ]]; if applied for twitter kit. Or you can simply past below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
// Swift
Crashlytics().debugMode = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

// Objective-C
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

Now build and run your app and check fabric UI window, it will move ahead to complete screen.

Comment: Solved this issue for me. Any idea why we have to do this though?

Comment: This didn't work for me for the exact issue with Crashlytics.

Answer (score 4):

It seems silly but sometimes you need to make a code change (like a simple `NSLog` statement) to kick the verification.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Just added some random line and voila! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me when stuck on last step "We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers." when installing through Firebase

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding a new app you need to be an Admin of your organization but you may just be a User.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue on Mac.

In my case the guide shown in the Fabric application was completely missing a crucial step: there was nothing about adding the API key!

So make sure your API key is added to info.plist, otherwise the application gets stuck at verifying installation.

Simply login to Fabric and follow this [manual installation guide](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install) to make sure everything gets done correctly. Once you complete the last step you can go straight to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have occurred the same problem. I run the app on iPhone. After I deleted the app and pressed `CMD + R` on iPhone, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed twitter/Digits kit using fabric before, then you will find `Fabric.with([Digits.self, Twitter.self])` in your "AppDelegate.swift" file . Replace it with the following code `Fabric.with([Digits.self, Twitter.self, Crashlytics.self])` if you want to use all three. Now press Cmd + R to finish the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to run the app with connectivity on the device/simulator, as indicated in [here](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/617559-stuck-on-verifying-installation-fabric-mac-on).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the app was already added to your team's account and that all you needed was an access to it. Here's a thread about the same issue: https://twittercommunity.com/t/hmmm-seems-like-your-kit-isnt-activating/73601/9.