# Kit isn't Activating - Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am having 6 targets with different bundle identifiers in my project, While 2 of them are added to crashlytics , but when i try to add another target to crashlytics it get stuck on Verification with message "kit isn't activating"

Where as if i try adding same bundle id to different account it just pass through.

have tried every solution from this link but no success.
[Crashlytics : stuck on "Verifying Installation..." step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757367/crashlytics-stuck-on-verifying-installation-step)

Comment: Check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836306/fabric-crashlytics-hmmm-seems-like-your-kit-isnt-activating-whilst-verifying
And
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757367/crashlytics-stuck-on-verifying-installation-step/34673708

Comment: @Nitish I mentioned that I tried every solution from the link you posted, Thanks for the time.

Comment: I got the support from support@fabric.io and they helped me figure out that some else from my team has already added the same bundle id. So I just need to get the invitation. So silly was the solution and i spent hours going mad about it.